# Missing AO output socket in Render Layers node

Tags: node-editor

Here's what I'm looking for:

[image]

Here's what I have:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Oh, nevermind. All I had to do was turn on AO in the Render Layers Tab->Passes->AO